# What is the history of the character “耻”?

Tags: characters, etymology, simplified-characters, traditional-characters, glyph-origin

The meaning of the word is “shame”. I often encounter the version which is written with a 止, but sometimes I confuse it with 恥. It seems that the meanings of 耻 and 恥 are both the same, just that one is a simplified character and the other, traditional.

How did two versions of the same word come about, and why would one be considered “simplified”, given that the number of strokes are similar?

Comment: Maybe because one of them is made "official" during the simplification process. You can also call it a variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>戰國・楚
簡
[image]
緇衣.28
郭店楚簡</kbd>
<kbd>篆
[image]
心部
說文解字</kbd><kbd>東漢
隸
[image]
樊敏碑</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

「恥」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_%282014%29): **/*n̥rəʔ/**, *humiliation/shame*) is comprised of semantic [「心」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=126) (*heart, mind*) and phonetic [「耳」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=430) (**/*C.nəʔ/**).

During times when [clerical script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) was in active use, the 「心」 portion of the character was sometimes corrupted into an additional sound hint 「止」 (**/*təʔ/**). This produces the variant 「耻」, which is the target of PRC's standardisation scheme.

<kbd>東漢
隸
[image]
樊敏碑</kbd>
　<kbd>東漢
隸
[image]
孔宙碑</kbd>
　<kbd>東漢
隸
[image]
池陽令</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

Comment: Why was 耻 “the target of PRC’s standardization scheme”?

Comment: @AxelTong I don't know. The PRC's standardisation documents don't really give comprehensive explanations most of the time. If I may make a wild guess, 耻 was chosen to reinforce the pronunciation of the word (耳 doesn't really fit the pronunciation of 恥 in Mandarin).

Answer (score 1):

恥 (u+6065) should be treated as the authentic one.

in 說文解字，”恥” was explained as “辱也。从心，耳聲。“, which implied the radical is “心”, the phonetic hint is “耳“

since the 康熙字典，恥 is belonged to the radical 心 (61)

however, the simplification in “that area” chose 耻 (u+803b), which is belonged to the radical 耳 (128).

[rant]

- shame (恥) is a feeling, that the character has the radical 心 (radical 61) is more appropriate
- 耻 (u+803b) has the radical 耳 (radical 128), it departs from the tradition severely.

[/rant]